# android threadid=1: stuck on threadid=29, giving up

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have problem with my app. its shutting down when i'm trying to start new activity. In logcat i receive this error:

```
threadid=1: stuck on threadid=29, giving up
Fatal signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT) at 0x00003591 (code=-6), thread 13797 (Thread-1600)
```

im putting my code here

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sklep extends Activity{


InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd; // tutaj


         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_sklep);                 



             final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

                mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2868941535761925/2313045696");
                requestNewInterstitial();

                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

...
and this is place when application is shutting down:
i tried to start new activity without intersitial ad, but it was still finishing app.

```
   bback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
           {

               @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                         mInterstitialAd.show();
                     }
                         else{

                     startActivity(intent);
                     finish();
                         }


                }


           });
```

Comment: What about your Manifest ? Are you sure you have all needed permissions ? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104107/fatal-signal-16-sigstkflt-has-been-occured-unexpectedly

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> Do i need more permissions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ads, but if you use startActivity(intent), maybe you need to declare the activity in your Manifest file.

Comment: Its declared. this intent is activity which contains SurfaceView. Sklep is activity which represent "market" in my game. Its starting every time when you reach next level. When you click bback button it should show ad and next start new intent(next level). I don't know how to deal with it, because on some devices it works fine, but on others it doesnt.

Comment: Can you post a LogCat to see what happens when your Activity closes ?

Comment: signal 16 seems to indicate a memory issue. If you are running it on an emulator, try to increase the ram and see if it still occures. Does this error occure, if you don't request an ad at all?

Comment: One of your threads, the anonymously-named "Thread-1600", has become unresponsive, and the VM is sending itself a signal to try to generate a stack trace. There should be a lot of noise in the log before this as the VM attempts to suspend the thread, and ideally a native stack dump in logcat right after this that shows where the thread was stuck. If the native stack dump is present, please paste it into your question. A representative sample of the VM output from before the crash might also be useful.

Comment: could you tell me how to recognise which thread is "1600"?  and what part of logcat would you like to see?